# chronos() function, ape package error in R: "Error in nlminb(start.para, f, g, control = opt.ctrl, lower = LOW, upper = UP):NA/NaN gradient evaluation

Tags: r, phylogeny

Tyring to make a newick tree with branch lengths included (no polytomy) into an ultrametric tree using the `chronos()` function from the `ape` package in R. Recieve the following message:

> Error in nlminb(start.para, f, g, control = opt.ctrl, lower = LOW,
> upper = UP) :    NA/NaN gradient evaluation

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi lou if you could share a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this would help figuring out what is happening with your specific case.